# PHP redirect if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using this if statement to redirect a user if the values in a .txt document is 0 but if it is 1 I want nothing to happen however I'm having some issues with my code.

This is my code currently:

```
$setup = require('setup.txt');

if ($setup === "0") {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "setup.php"    </script>';
}
```

The setup.txt document currently contains the value 0.

Comment: so check if it equals 1 *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: I have tried '=' '==' and '===' but still not working

Comment: you're checking for a string, rather than an integer; seems like it to me. Harder to say without seeing what's inside that text file of yours. anyway, see the answers below. I'm not submitting an answer.

Comment: the document just has the number 0

Comment: then get rid of the quotes if ($setup === 0) or see Tom's answer

Comment: where are we with the question; none of the answers worked? Plus, if your file contains a space/spaces or a carriage return, that may also affect its proper execution/success.

Comment: I still can't get it working

Comment: what about the other answers below, most particularly the most upvoted?

Answer (score 2):

I'd look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) as to the proper usage of the require function.

```
if (file_get_contents('setup.txt') == "0") {
      header('Location: /setup.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the header function if you have not already sent output to the browser.

```
$setup = file_get_contents('setup.txt');
if ($setup == "0") {
  header('Location: /setup.php');
}
```

Since all PHP is executed before the output the site. Use this option first.

You can not use `include()` / `require()` to transfer as a variable, like you have. Use `file_get_contents()` to achieve the results.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to redirect the page

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, I updated the answer, after realizing the you where actually including the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
 $setup = file_get_contents('setup.txt');
 if (trim($setup) == "0") {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "setup.php"    </script>';
 }
?>
```